# Formatting MM/dd in gridview date row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to format a date on a grid view to only show the month and the day:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Monday" HeaderText="Monday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Monday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
     DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

It is no working. Also, when I look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

I don't see this formatting as an option. How do I achieve this?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Is "Monday" a datetime field, right?

Comment: The query is pretty complex that is displayed in the gridview. There are multiple views that are shown, the first row has a date the others don't. I'll post a pic right now for clarification.

Comment: It's not working means date is not in the format desired. As show in the above pic 2013/10/07 is not what I want. I want 10/07.

Comment: _"I don't see this formatting as an option"_ Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)  for a complete list of format strings.

Comment: I assume that `2013/10/07` is a `varchar`. Then your best option is to change that into `datetime`. Otherwise you always have to convert it to a `DateTime` first, for example by using `CAST` or `CONVERT`(presuming SQL-Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change that column into a TemplateField. Then I would change the Text to..

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday","{0:MM/dd}") %>'
```

This should work for you. The entire TemplateField for and just the ItemTemplate should look something similar to this..

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday" SortExpression="Monday">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMonday" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday","{0:MM/dd}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Data Field `Monday` a `DateTime` field in your result.

If it isn't a datetime field, you will need to convert it your Sql statement.

For example:

```
Select <expression> as Monday....
```

to

```
Select Cast(<expression> as datetime) as Monday....
```